# Is it possible to make a list comprehension from the following function?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

There is a function that returns a sum of integers from list x that are greater than integer y. If there is none of the numbers greater than y the function returns 0.

```
def sum_greater(x, y):
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] > y:
            result = result + x[i]
    return result
```

My question: is it possible (and if it is than how) to make a list comprehension from this function?

Comment: I didn`t think about it. It has to return 0 if all of the numbers are less than y. But when I run the module in the shell (sum_greater([1,2,3,4,5,6], 4)) it returned 11, so I thought it worked correctly

Comment: That returns 0, not 11.  Perhaps you gave us the wrong code?

Comment: you are right, I copied the wrong code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sum()` function with a generator expression:

```
sum(i for i in x if i > y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since 0 is the natural result of the sum of nothing, that doesn't need any special handling. You can send a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to the built-in `sum`:

```
def sum_greater(x, y):
    return sum(i for i in x if i>y)
```